# How could I run a WM6.0 program on WM5.0

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile

I have a testing PDA running on WM6.0. But my client uses WM5.0.
Is it possible to build the program(c# by VS) so that I can test on my PDA and run on my client's PDA?
(emulator doesnt take count)

Or

any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you don't use any of the new 6.0 stuff and you should be fine. With your test pda being different to the platform you want to deploy on there is no way to guarantee that it is a valid test, but the combination of testing on a real 6.0 device and a 5.0 emulator should come reasonably close.

Comment: +1, Yep, the Windows Mobile Emulator is quite good. It also allows to receive and send SMS's and to have a fake radio module attachted. Oh, don't forget about GPS. This should give a quite real experience to your program.

Comment: Can I run WM5.0 program on WM6.0 platform?

Comment: Yes, it's only WM7 that doesn't have backward compatibility.